# The function $(1+x)(1+x^4)(1+x^{16})(1+x^{64})\cdots =\prod_{n\geq 0} (1+x^{4^n})$

Tags: contest-math, infinite-product

Let $$f(x)=(1+x)(1+x^4)(1+x^{16})(1+x^{64})\cdots=\prod_{n\geq 0} (1+x^{4^n})$$

Then what is $f^{-1}(\frac{8}{5f(3/8)})?$

The answer should be a rational number.

My attempt: I tried to take a log of the expression to turn it into a sum, but that did not simplify. So I am clueless on how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does the sequence continue? Do the exponents follow powers of $4$, or is there some other pattern?

Comment: @Arthur Yes $$$$

Comment: @Displayname: Yes to "the exponents follow powers of $4$", or yes to "there is some other pattern"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Powers of 4. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Obviously, the answer is $x$ satisfying $f(x)f(3/8)=8/5$

Comment: Notice that $f(x^4)(1+x) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's hard to say things about $f(x)$ for general $x$. But we have 
\begin{align}
(1-x) f(x) f(x^2) &= (1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\dotsb \\
 &= (1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\dotsb \\
 &= (1-x^4)(1+x^4)(1+x^8) \dotsb \\
 &= (1-x^8)(1+x^8) \dotsb \\
 &= \dots = 1.
\end{align}
(Assuming convergence.)

If $x = f^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{5f(3/8)}\right)$, then $\frac58 \cdot f(\frac38) \cdot f(x)=1$, and the above identity tells us that $\frac58 \cdot f(\frac38) \cdot f(\frac{9}{64}) = 1$. So one possible answer is $\frac{9}{64}$.

To verify that this solution is valid (i.e., to verify convergence) and that it is the only solution, note that $$\log f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \log\left(1 + x^{4^n}\right) \le \sum_{n \ge 1} x^{4^n}$$ which converges for $|x| < 1$, and $f$ is increasing (because each factor is increasing) and therefore injective.

Comment: Wow! Great solution!

Comment: We can also see that $f(x)=\sum_n a_nx^n$ where $a_n$ is $1$ if $n$ is a sum of distinct powers of $4$ and $0$ otherwise. By comparison with $\sum x^n$ this converges absolutely for $|x|<1$ -- and it obviously diverges for $x=1$, so the radius of convergence is $1$. ($f$ is [lacunary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function)).